# How do I create .txt files where the filenames are taken from elements of an array?

Tags: perl

I have an array (`@engineer_list`) which contains the names of engineers.  For each element within the array, I want to create a .txt file where the filename is the name of the engineer.

```
foreach (@engineer_list) {
     open (ENGINEER_MINIMUMS,">$engineer_list.txt") or die ("Can't open $engineer_list.txt for writing\n");
}
```

I know this doesn't work because `$engineer_list` is a variable and not the element currently open within the loop.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create the iterator variable `$engineer_list` in the `foreach` loop:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @engineer_list = qw(edison tesla);
foreach my $engineer_list (@engineer_list) {
    open (ENGINEER_MINIMUMS,">$engineer_list.txt") or die ("Can't open $engineer_list.txt for writing\n");
}
```

This opens 2 files named:

```
edison.txt
tesla.txt
```

Note: it just creates 2 empty files; you need to add code to write to the files, if that is what you want.

Refer to [Foreach loops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops)

Answer (score 1):

If you omit an iterator variable from a `foreach` loop, then Perl will use `$_` as the iterator variable. That means the simplest fix that gets your code working as expected is this:

```
foreach (@engineer_list) {
    open (ENGINEER_MINIMUMS,">$_.txt") # Use $_ here
        or die ("Can't open $_.txt for writing\n"); # and here
}
```

However, current best practices are to use lexical scalar variables for filehandles and the three-argument version of `open()` (which separates the mode character from the filename). So your code becomes this:

```
foreach (@engineer_list) {
    open (my $engineer_fh, '>', "$_.txt")
        or die ("Can't open $_.txt for writing\n");
}
```

Finally, it's a good idea to include `$!` in the error message, so you know why Perl failed to open your file:

```
foreach (@engineer_list) {
    open (my $engineer_fh, '>', "$_.txt")
        or die ("Can't open $_.txt for writing: $!\n");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use your own name for the iterator variable:

```
foreach my $engineer (@engineer_list) {
    open (my $engineer_fh, '>', "$engineer.txt")
        or die ("Can't open $engineer.txt for writing: $!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.30;
use warnings;

my @engineer_list = qw(eng1 eng2 eng3 eng4);
foreach my $engineer (@engineer_list) {
    open (my $fho, ">", "${engineer}.txt")  or die "Cannot open file.\n $!";
    print $fho "$engineer\n"; #writes name of engineer to file to file.
}
```