# I'd like to understand why unlink doesn't work for one specific file

Tags: windows, perl, permissions, unlink

I have a script that creates some temp files for processing later and when they are not needed anymore I want to delete them.  The file that won't unlink is always the very last file that's created inside a `while` loop.  Feels like a closing issue, but I can't see it.
Here's the relevant pieces of code:

```
 # Creates a temp file for each of the guys with every stock item from the products listed against their name.
 open ENG_LIST, 'engineer_list.txt' or die "Can't open engineer_list.txt\n";
 mkdir './Temp';
 while ($line = <ENG_LIST>) {
     chomp $line;
     @products = split(/\|/, $line);
     $engineer = shift @products;
     push @engineer_list, $engineer;
     $fh = "./Temp/$engineer.txt";
     foreach $product (@products) {
         open $output, ">>:raw", "./Temp/$engineer.txt" or die "Unable to open ./Temp/$engineer.txt for appending: $!\n";
         open $input, "<:raw", "./Products/$product.txt" or die "Unable to open ./Products/$product.txt for reading: $!\n";
         print {$output} <$input>;
     }
     close ($fh);
     undef @products;
 }
 close (ENG_LIST);
```

Then there's some processing I'm happy with.  Then the clean up routine:

```
 # Cleaning up all the temp files.  Need to fix this because it doesn't work!
 @del_files = glob ('./Temp/*.txt');
 foreach $del_file (@del_files) {
     chomp $del_file;
     close ($del_file);
     unlink "$del_file";
 }
 rmtree ('./Temp');
```

I've tried using chmod, but I'm getting nowhere with that either.  The error is always

```
cannot unlink file - Permission denied
```

Comment: `close ($fh);` - `$fh` isn't a filehandle. `$input` and `$output`  are though - and you never close them. Try closing them when you're done with them to see if things improve.  `close ($del_file);` also tries to close a non-filehandle.

Comment: People have brought up you trying to close non-file handles in a [previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77983697/how-to-do-i-rename-a-file-using-data-found-within-it)... Surprised you're still doing it.

Comment: And I know it's [been suggested you use modern lexical file handles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77717816/9952196) (`open my $output, ...`) but I'm not sure if one of the benefits has been brought up - they're automatically closed when the reference count on them goes to 0 (when it goes out of scope etc.) so you don't have to remember to do so manually.

Comment: Also, always check `close` -- `close $filehandle or ...` (and `unlink` for that matter)

Comment: If you had used `use strict; use warnings;` you would have gotten a warning about trying to close a non-existing file handle.

Comment: @TedLyngmo All that is now fixed and it's still the same.

Comment: @PeteG You then need to update the code in the question so that we can see what it looks like now.

Comment: @Shawn I tried that too, and still the same error.  If it closes automatically outside of the scope then I should be able to unlink it, but I can't.

Comment: @Bork I do use strict and warnings.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Will do.  I'm having to learn how to use this site correctly also.

Comment: @PeteG Then why did you not report that you got multiple errors regarding `close`, e.g. `close on unopened file handle`. Did you declare all your variables at the top of the program?

Comment: @Bork I don't get those errors and have declared all the variables at the top of the file.

Comment: @PeteG I hear what you are saying, and I am saying that that is impossible. If you have warnings on, and you try to close something that is not a file handle, then you will get that error. The only way this would not happen is if you are running some other code, or if your error messages are being diverted, like to an error log file.

Comment: @PeteG You should declare variables in the smallest scope possible, right where they are needed. Not at the top. This is good practice, and will help with encapsulation and readability

Comment: What OS? ______

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly output `cannot unlink file - Permission denied`. Please post the code you actually ran

Comment: @ikegami Windows.  I'm using Strawberry Perl.

Comment: @ikegami Okay, i'm paraphrasing.  
"C:\Users\peteg\Desktop\Stock cruncher - NEW>perl stock_cruncher8.pl
cannot unlink file for Temp\Steve Wake.txt: Permission denied at stock_cruncher8.pl line 165."

Comment: Re "*i'm paraphrasing*", Obviously. Again, please post the code you actually ran. It's stupid to waste out time on a program that may or may not have the problem.

Comment: @ikegami I edited the original question which shows the exact sections I am using.  I get the same problem.  I hope that was correct, but now some of the replies reference the original question which makes them look odd.

Comment: Just as before, your updated code can't possibly output `cannot unlink file - Permission denied`. Again, please post the code you actually ran (or run the code you actually posted).

Comment: You should avoid changing the code in your question so that it no longer matches the answers you've been given.

Comment: I've rolled back your changes to the code since they invalidated at least 2 answers. Please ask a new question with the new code if needed.

Comment: @Dada That's fine.  I only did it because someone asked me to.

Answer (score 3):

The argument for [`close`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close) is the same as the first one for [`open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open): The name of the file handle. This code:

```perl
     $fh = "./Temp/$engineer.txt";
     foreach $product (@products) {
         open $output, ">>:raw", "./Temp/$engineer.txt" or die "Unable to open ./Temp/$engineer.txt for appending: $!\n";
         open $input, "<:raw", "./Products/$product.txt" or die "Unable to open ./Products/$product.txt for reading: $!\n";
         print {$output} <$input>;
     }
     close ($fh);
```

Should be changed to something like:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;  # always use these

     my $file = "./Temp/$engineer.txt";
     foreach my $product (@products) {
         open my $output, ">>:raw", $file or die "Unable to open $file for appending: $!\n";
         open my $input, "<:raw", "./Products/$product.txt" or die "Unable to open ./Products/$product.txt for reading: $!\n";
         print {$output} <$input>;
     }
    # no close needed
```

While you can close a file handle explicitly, you can also use a lexical file handle, which is automatically closed when the file handle variable goes out of scope. Which it will do in a loop.

The reason your last file is not deleted is that none of your file handles are ever closed, since you use global variables, and never close them. But you do overwrite them each time you enter that loop. But the last loop remains when all the iterations are done, hence that file handle remains open.

You might also have caught this by checking the return value of [`unlink`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink)

```
unlink $del_file or warn "Cannot unlink '$del_file': $!";
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've edited the original question and it still happens.  I think the reason the code currently wasn't explicitly closing these file handles is because it didn't seem to make a difference and I've tried so many different ways and this is just where it is today.

Comment: @PeteG Make sure that the code and error messages is matched exactly to what you get when you run the code. Next step is to try and recreate your issue by making a small sample program that can be run on its own to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `close ($fh);`. You would need to `close ($input);` and `close ($output);`. You're trying to delete/ `unlink()` a file that is in use.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, many programs (incl Perl's `open`) open files with share protection that prevents them from being deleted while still open. This results in error EPERM (Permission denied) when someone attempts.

Since you didn't provide the program that results in the error, I can't help any further than pointing out you need to ensure the file handle is closed before you attempt to unlink the file.

Note that the open handle might be in another process. This commonly happens when using files on a One Drive volume, for example, since One Drive locks changed files during synchronization.